# Same random images on same page (I want to show different random images)

Tags: javascript, random

I am new in here, my code is there, works fine but sometimes i see same image on the page. How can i show it to be different every image.

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript> 

var theImages = new Array() 
theImages[0] = 'cow.png' 
theImages[1] = 'donkey.png' 
theImages[2] = 'monkey.png' 

var otherImages = new Array() 
otherImages[0] = 'cow.png' 
otherImages[1] = 'donkey.png' 
 otherImages[2] = 'monkey.png' 

var otherImages2 = new Array() 
otherImages2[0] = 'cow.png' 
otherImages2[1] = 'donkey.png' 
 otherImages2[2] = 'monkey.png' 




var j = 0 
var p = theImages.length; 
var preBuffer = new Array() 
var preBuffer2 = new Array() 
var preBuffer3 = new Array() 
var preBuffer4 = new Array() 

for (i = 0; i < p; i++){ 

preBuffer[i] = new Image() 
preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i] 
preBuffer2[i] = new Image() 
preBuffer2[i].src = otherImages[i] 
preBuffer3[i] = new Image() 
preBuffer3[i].src = theImages[i] 
} 


var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1)); 
var otherImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
var otherImage2 = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));  
function showImage(){ 
document.write('<img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'">'); 
} 

function showImage2(){ 
document.write('<img src="'+otherImages[otherImage]+'">'); 
} 

function showImage3(){ 
document.write('<img src="'+otherImages2[otherImage2]+'">'); 
} 


</SCRIPT> 
</head>
<body>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript> 
showImage(); 
</SCRIPT> 

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript> 
showImage2(); 
</SCRIPT> 

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript> 
showImage3(); 
</SCRIPT> 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `theImages`, `otherImages` and `otherImages2` always contain the same images? Are you trying ot make it so that the 3 images displayed in the body are always different? What is the purpose of the `preBuffer` arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to ensure that each randomly selected image is not the same as the others.

You could use while loops to repeat the randomisation until the selected image index does not match the others:

```
var whichImage;
var otherImage;
var otherImage2;

whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1)); 

while (otherImage == whichImage) {
    otherImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
}

while (otherImage2 == whichImage || otherImage2 == otherImage) {
    otherImage2 = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
}
```

Be careful if your arrays are likely to change size as you could get stuck in a loop. For example, if one array only has a size of 1.